# Generic Repository vs Simple DbContext vs Extension Methode c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, repository, extension-methods

I'm stuck in a decision that which one of these ways to use in my project.
Project is asp.net core mvc and layers are shown at this image(just to clear what i am looking for)

[image]

At first I used generic Repository Pattern for this project and codes are this

```
public interface IGenericRepository<TEntity> : IDisposable where TEntity:BaseModel
{
    IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntitiesQuery();
    Task<TEntity> GetEntityById(long entityId);
    Task<TEntity> GetEntityByIdAsNoTracking(long entityId);
    Task AddEntity(TEntity entity);
    void UpdateEntity(TEntity entity);
    void SoftRemoveEntity(TEntity entity);
    Task SoftRemoveEntityById(long entityId);
    void HardRemoveEntity(TEntity entity);
    Task HardRemoveEntityById(long entityId);
    Task SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Its worked perfectly but I read that this generic repository pattern is old these days and also there is a problem when I want to use some entities in one service I have to inject each entity separately on my service which makes this harder on my test project.
Imagine this scenario that in my AccountService.cs on Register method I want to modify 4 entity User-Role-Log-Score so my constructor would be like this :

```
public class AccountService : IAccountService
{
private readonly IGenericRepository<User> _userRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Role> _roleRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Log> _logRepository;
private readonly IGenericRepository<Score> _scoreRepository;

public AccountService(IGenericRepository<User> userRepository, IGenericRepository<Role> 
roleRepository, IGenericRepository<Log> logRepository, IGenericRepository<Score> 
scoreRepository)
{
    _userRepository = userRepository;
    _roleRepository = roleRepository;
    _logRepository = logRepository;
    _scoreRepository = scoreRepository;
}
```

So this is huge and I do not think that is a good Idia to use something like this so I have 2 other options one is use DbContext directly without no Repositoy at all and one more way  is using extension Methodes for DbContext like this

```
public static class DbContextExtension
{
   public static IQueryable<TEntity> GetEntitiesQuery<TEntity>(this MainDbContext 
   dbContext) where TEntity : BaseModel
   {
      return dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AsQueryable();
   }

   public static async Task AddEntity<TEntity>(this MainDbContext dbContext, TEntity 
   entity) where TEntity : BaseModel
   {
     entity.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
     entity.LastUpdateDate = entity.CreateDate;
     await dbContext.Set<TEntity>().AddAsync(entity);
   }
}
```

If I use this way I only inject my dbContext once and I use every entity I want
So now Help me which way is better in performance and everything? which one do you suggest ? and why?

1: Generic Repository

2: DbContext Without Repository and unit of work

3: Extension Methode

Comment: What is the point of extension methods? Why don't just override methods or just declare them in `MainDbContext`? Having overridden/added methods allows you to mock them while testing. Seems you hide call to `.Set<T>()` in your extension methods and some properties setting - you can also inherit from `DbSet<T>` and override needed methods.

Comment: While this is a good formulated question, the answers will be highly opinion-based. Just pick, what best works for you and your team. Every approach has the one or other drawback. I normally work directly with the DbContext or take the DDD approach, but it is really up to you to pick one.

Comment: @RomanDoskoch The point of using extension method is Avoid writing duplicate code like in AddEntity I dont duplicate createDate and UpdateDate in my sevice each time but i feel its weird thats what i am asked

Comment: @Saeed, but you can just declare new method in `MainDbContext` (instance method) and have the same logic there.

Comment: @Oliver yes you right but I am worried about future project development so whats your idia about extension method way ? is it regular? or its just Waste of system resources?

Comment: @Saeed, here is a simple example - https://dotnetfiddle.net/JNJqnc

Comment: @RomanDoskoch Sounds like a good method. Its very better than extension . thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using IOC container to register all IRepositories as singletons，this is a good way to layer the modules. Each IPocoRepository should contain the common CURD APIs and it's unique business APIs.

PS: I don't like the generic solution.

Comment: That may be the first time I've seen someone recommend a singleton repository..